# sudo issue during echo something to a root file

Tags: sudo, echo

I have a problem, during write something into a root file:

```
$ ll /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-2/power/wakeup
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Feb 16 17:28 /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-2/power/wakeup
$ sudo echo disabled > /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-2/power/wakeup
bash: /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-2/power/wakeup: Permission denied
```

even it did not ask me for password.

1. How can I solve this?
2. Why I can't use `sudo` directly?

Comment: `echo disabled | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-2/power/wakeup > /dev/null`

Comment: @Costas, thanks, and can you tell me why I can't directly use `sudo`?

Comment: In your line at fact there are two commands: `echo` and `>` (redirection). First is sudoed, but the second didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use sudo with redirection, because the redirection is done by your original shell which runs as your own user code. It tries to set up a file descriptor for the file mentioned after the >, which fails as your user is not able to write to it.

Costas's method works, as does spawning a subshell:

```
sudo sh -c "echo disabled > /sys/bus/usb/device/3-2/power/wakeup"
```